# Why 'For Loop' is iterating just once, even though the parameters are totally valid?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js

The function is iterated 3 times when console logged, but while returning an image tag, it just runs only once!

```
const imgSources = [
  "https://source.unsplash.com/164x130",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/144x144",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080",
];

    let fetchImg = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < imgSources.length; i++) {
    // console.log(imgSources[i]);
    return <Image src={imgSources[i]} height={100} width={100} />;
  }
};
```

I'm using it like this below:

```
<div>{fetchImg()}</div>
```

Comment: You are using return in for loop which breaks for loop in first time that is why seeing only single image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning after the first iteration. You can use the `map` function to achieve the result you are looking for:

```
const imgSources = [
  "https://source.unsplash.com/164x130",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/144x144",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080",
];


let fetchImg = () => {

    // do something else here

    return imgSources.map((img, index) => 
           <Image src={img} height={100} width={100} key={index} />
    );
}
```

[Here are some more details regarding the use of `key`s](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children)

Comment: The first example is not good, you should not have side-effects inside map (mutating things outside of the map function is not good practice), the second one is good, leveraging the array that is returned from the map function.

Comment: @tperamaki I thought so :) Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are returning in the function

```
let fetchImg = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < imgSources.length; i++) {
    // console.log(imgSources[i]);
    return <Image src={imgSources[i]} height={100} width={100} />;
  }
};
```

You should save these images in an another array and use the array to access the images instead:

```
let images = [];
let fetchImg = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < imgSources.length; i++) {
    // console.log(imgSources[i]);
    images.push(<Image src={imgSources[i]} height={100} width={100} />);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you return it'll break look, Use map function to create array.

```
const imgSources = [
  "https://source.unsplash.com/164x130",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/144x144",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080",
];

let fetchImg = () => imgSources.map((img) => <Image src={img} height={100} width={100} key={img} />);
```

Comment: This is ok, maybe just add the key parameter to the Image?